# SQL: Buscar dato con un select dentro de un update

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo una duda en SQL. Estoy tratando de hacer un **update** donde un dato presente en una *tabla A* tiene que buscarse y machiar dentro de otra *tabla B* (donde puede estar repetido, en tal caso traer el mas reciente via campo **LAST_UPD**) para traer otros datos presentes en el mismo row obtenido de B (ejemplo: B.estado).

```
UPDATE TABLA A
SET A.ESTADO= B.ESTADO
WHERE A.X_LINEA=B.LINEA and (CONDICION REPETIDO MAS RECIENTE DE B)
```

**Como dato:** los comandos *TOP* y *LIMIT* no funcionan con esta version de sql *(ROWNUM si)*.

Para tener en cuenta: ambas tablas pueden ser muy largas y los valores desordenados ya que la DB ya tiene varios años

¿Me podrian dar una mano para cerrar esto?

Gracias!

Comment: Para tener en cuenta: ambas tablas pueden ser muy largas y los valores desordenados ya que la DB ya tiene varios años

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Oracle no tiene el comando TOP y uno usa ROWNUM para obtener un número de registros a partir del resultado de la consulta. Eso es claro. Te sugiero acudir a la documentación.

Comment: Nota al margen, no es que top y limit no funcionan con esta version de sql. Si no que directamente no existen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update tabla_A a
set estado = 
(select b.estado from tabla_b b
 where b.LAST_UPD = 
     (select max(c.LAST_UPD ) from tabla_b c
     where c.clave = b.clave)
 and b.campojoin = a.campojoin 
)
```

Con esta consulta actualizas el estado de Tabla a a partir del estado de Tabla b, siendo este último el registro mas reciente ( eso se hace con la segunda subconsulta).
El join ente tabla_A y tabla_b no se porque campos es, por eso lo deje génerico.
Espero te sirva, sino pasa mas detalle de tus tablas así queda mas explícito.

Abrazo.

Comment: muchas gracias! Me sirvio la respuesta, me fue mas perfomante de lo que tenia

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de EduardoGarcia es correcta. Sin embargo, suponiendo que estás trabajando en oracle (oracle sql developer es sólo la interfaz y puede usarse para conectarse a muchas BD), para un volumen significativo de registros puede usarse MERGE, que es más eficiente

```
MERGE INTO target_table 
USING source_table 
ON search_condition
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET col1 = value1, col2 = value2,...
        WHERE <update_condition>
        [DELETE WHERE <delete_condition>]
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (col1,col2,...)
        values(value1,value2,...)
        WHERE <insert_condition>;
```